# Помогите вывести минимальное число (ошибку выдает:TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу программу, которая в последовательности натуральных чисел определяет **минимальное** число, `кратное 3`.

Программа получает на вход количество чисел в последовательности, а затем сами числа. В последовательности всегда имеется число, `кратное 3`. Количество чисел не превышает `1000`. Введённые числа не превышают `30 000`. **Программа должна вывести одно число — минимальное число, кратное 3.**

```
n = int(input())
k = 0
for i in range(n):
    a = int(input())
    if a%3 == 0:
        minimum = min(a)
print(minimum)
```

Comment: 15.2 Напишите программу, которая в последовательности натуральных чисел определяет минимальное число, кратное 3. Программа получает на вход количество чисел в последовательности, а затем сами числа. В последовательности всегда имеется число, кратное 3. Количество чисел не превышает 1000. Введённые числа не превышают 30 000. Программа должна вывести одно число — минимальное число, кратное 3.

Comment: А что вы тут хотели получить `min(a)` ? Допустим `a = 3`, что дало бы `min(3)`? `min` принимает 2 параметра для сравнения чисел и 1 параметр для минимального значения из коллекции (то, что можно итерировать)

Comment: При вводе данных (Input) я бы ввел 3 ,21,12 и 31 и я бы хотел вывести минимальное кратное 3

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ОГЭ Информатика Задание 15.2 не могу справиться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1082998/%d0%9e%d0%93%d0%ad-%d0%98%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-15-2-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f)

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пишите `n = 10` `for i in range(n)` Это означает, что вы берете числа от 1 до 9
А `for i in range(n + 1)` это уже от 1 до 10.

Теперь если вы решаете через функцию `range` вам не нужно использовать функцию `min` , а просто вернуть первое значение, которое нацело делится на 3.

```
n = int(input('ЧИСЛО: '))
    for i in range(n+1):
        if i == 0: # Если не добавить это вернется 0
            continue # так же, чтобы не вернуло 0 можно написать for i in range(1, n)
        if i % 3 == 0:
            print(i)
            break
```

вывод:

```
$ python test.py
ЧИСЛО: 55555555
3
```

Если вы решаете через список рандомных чисел, то нужно будет воспользоватся `min`

```
l1 = [47851, 819289, 51778, 5878, 145256, 145587, 2456, 1456, 915, 879, 37895, 1, 5, 
     7, 8, 99999999, 891]

def min_div_by_three(num_list):
    return min([i for i in num_list if i % 3 == 0])

print(min_div_by_three(l1))
```

вывод:

```
$ python test.py
879
```

Вот ещё код с генерированием списка на десерт)

```
from random import randint

def min_div_by_three(num_list: list):
    return min([i for i in num_list if i % 3 == 0])

def gen_list(start: int = 111, end: int = 9999999, range_var: int = 1001):
    num = []
    for _ in range(range_var):
        num.append(randint(start, end))
    return num

print(min_div_by_three(gen_list()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
n = int(input())
items = []

for i in range(n):
    a = int(input())
    if a % 3 == 0:
        items.append(a)

print(min(items))
```

или так:

```
n = int(input())
min_num = None

for i in range(n):
    a = int(input())
    if a % 3 == 0:
        if min_num is None:
            min_num = a
        else:
            min_num = min(min_num, a)

print(min_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема вашего кода вот в этой строке:

```
...
        minimum = min(a)
...
```

Функция `min` возвращает минимальное число из **списка** (кортежа/словаря/множества) чисел, а вы пытаетесь передать ей просто число.

Вариант валидного использования функции `min` для решения вашей задачи:

```py
n = int(input())
data = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]

divided = [elem for elem in data if not elem%3]
print(min(divided))
```