# ОГЭ Информатика Задание 15.2 не могу справиться

Tags: python, python-3.x

15.2 Напишите программу, которая в последовательности натуральных чисел определяет минимальное число, кратное 3. Программа получает на вход количество чисел в последовательности, а затем сами числа. В последовательности всегда имеется число, кратное 3. Количество чисел не превышает 1000. Введённые числа не превышают 30 000. Программа должна вывести одно число — минимальное число, кратное 3.

Вот что у меня получается:

```
n = int(input())
k = 0
for i in range(n):
    a = int(input())
    if a%3 == 0:
        minimum = min(a)
print(minimum)
```

Выдает ошибку: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Ну так если Вы "полный чайник", зачем взяли экзамен по данному предмету?

Comment: Зачем задавать два одинаковых вопроса?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
n = int(input())#Получает кол-во чисел
minimum = 30000 #Максимально возможное число
for i in range(n): #Выполняет цикл n-ое кол-во раз
    a = int(input()) #Просит ввести число
    if a % 3 == 0 and a < minimum: #Идёт проверка на кратность 3 и является ли оно меньше minimum
        minimum = a #Присваивает значение a minimum, если выполнено условие выше
print(minimum) #Выводит минимальное число
```